# Connect icCube with Reshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, iccube

in icCube 5.1 there is no Redshift as list of supported JDBC connections.

How to create a data source in icCube on Amazon Redshift ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first solution is using the Postgres jdbc driver. Redshift is based on Postgres so it also works (for how long is a good question).

[image: iccube-redshift-postgres]

The second is a bit more complicated as you need to add Reshift jdbc driver to icCube. First download jdbc driver from amazon from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html), after follow this [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375238/how-to-install-a-new-jar-into-iccube/) to add a library to icCube.

Once done you've to configure a new data-source :

[image: iccube-redshift-jdbc]