# How to install a new JAR into icCube

Tags: jdbc, iccube

Is there any way to add a JAR to icCube install to make it available to MDX JAVA integration, JDBC data source, etc...?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add the JAR into the icCube lib directory and possibly t update accordingly the CLASSPATH:

Windows (.exe)

```
- copy the JAR into C:\Program Files\icCube\5.1\lib
- restart icCube
```

Windows (.bat)

```
- copy the JAR into C:\Program Files\icCube\5.1\lib
- edit the C:\Program Files\icCube\5.1\bin\icCube.bat file to add the JAR to the CLASSPATH (e.g., SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;../lib/new-jar.jar)
- restart icCube
```

Linux

```
- copy the JAR into /opt/icCube/lib
- edit the file /opt/icCube/bin/icCube.sh to add the JAR to the CLASSPATH (e.g., CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$ICCUBE/lib/new-jar.jar" )
- restart icCube
```

MacOS

```
- copy the JAR into the icCube.app package Contents / Java / lib
- edit the file Contents / Info.plist to add the new JAR to the <key>JVMClassPath</key>
- restart icCube
```